# "Login failed for user. Cannot open database requested by the login. The login failed" when trying to restore sql server database with delphi

Tags: sql-server, delphi

I'm currently learning programming and I'm trying new stuff, so I tried to make a backup and restore it with the program. I eventually figured it out and managed to make backups and restore them successfully. The problem occurred when I moved the code in threads. I eventually managed to work out the back up thread, but I'm stuck on the restore part. This is my restore thread.

```
type
  TThreadRestoreBackUp = class( TThread )
  protected
    procedure Execute(); override;
  public
    DataSource : TMSDataSource;
    Connection : TMSConnection;
    Query : TMSQuery;
    var
      DBName, RestorePath, dbRPath, dbRLogPath : string;
      differentDB : Boolean;
  end;
```

As you can see I've created DataSource, Connection and TMSQuery for the thread. I did that because I read that it's not good to use the ones I have in the main form. This is how I create and execute the thread:

```
procedure TfrmCreateBackUp.btnRestoreClick(Sender: TObject);

var
  RestoreBackUp : BackUpThread.TThreadRestoreBackUp;

begin
  RestoreBackUp := BackUpThread.TThreadRestoreBackUp.Create(True);
  RestoreBackUp.FreeOnTerminate := True;
  try
    RestoreBackUp.DataSource := frmMain.MSDSChanges;
    RestoreBackUp.Connection := frmMain.MSConnLyubenAirport;
    RestoreBackUp.Query := frmMain.MSQChanges;
    RestoreBackUp.DBName := edtDBName.Text;
    RestoreBackUp.DifferentDB := tcxCheckBoxNewDB.Checked;
    RestoreBackUp.RestorePath := cxbeChoosePath.Text;
    RestoreBackUp.Start;
  except on EConvertError do
    RestoreBackUp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I'm giving the connection, datasource and tmsQuery the data from the ones I have in main. Also I get the dbName and different paths needed for the restore from components on the restore form. This is the code in the thread

```
procedure TThreadRestoreBackUp.Execute();
begin
  dbRPath := 'E:\ClientDBS\';
  dbRLogPath := 'E:\ClientDBS\';

  if DifferentDB then
  begin
    dbRPath := dbRPath + DBName + '.mdf';
    dbRLogPath := dbRLogPath + DBName + '.ldf';

    Query.SQL.Text := 'If DB_ID(' + QuotedStr(DBName) + ') IS NOT NULL ' +
      'USE ' + DBName + ' SELECT * FROM Flights';

    Query.Execute;

    if Query.IsEmpty then
    begin
      Query.SQL.Text := 'USE master RESTORE DATABASE ' + DbName +
        ' FROM DISK = ' + QuotedStr(RestorePath) +
        ' WITH RECOVERY, MOVE ' + QuotedStr(DBName) +
        ' TO ' + QuotedStr(dbRPath) + ', MOVE ' + QuotedStr(DBName + '_log') +
        ' TO ' + QuotedStr(dbRLogPath);

      Query.Execute;
    end
    else
    begin
      Query.SQL.Text := 'USE master ALTER DATABASE [' + DBName + ']' +
        ' SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE' +
        ' RESTORE DATABASE ' + DbName +
        ' FROM DISK = ' + QuotedStr(RestorePath) +
        ' WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY ' + 'ALTER DATABASE [' + DBName + ']' +
        ' SET ONLINE';

      test := Query.SQL.Text;

      Query.Execute;
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    DBName := Connection.Database;

    Query.SQL.Text := 'USE master ALTER DATABASE [' + DBName +
      '] SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE' +
      ' RESTORE DATABASE [' + DBName +
      '] FROM DISK = ' + QuotedStr(RestorePath) +
      ' WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY ALTER DATABASE [' + DBName +
      '] SET ONLINE';

    test := Query.SQL.Text;

    Query.Execute;
  end;

  Query.SQL.Text := 'USE [' + DBName + ']';
  Query.Execute;

  DataSource.Free;
  Connection.Free;
  Query.Free;
end;
```

The code gets the paths needed to make the restore. The reason I've done it that way is because I want the user to be able to either restore in the same db used, or restore in another one, which may or may not already exist. After getting the paths to the string variables, I have the if statement, that checks if the box in the form for different db is checked. If yes, then it goes and tries to query with the db and if the query is empty then clearly it doesn't exist, so I try to restore it and move the files needed to be moved for the restore, if it exists then it just restores with replace. And obviously if different db isn't checked then it just restores in the one I use anyway. But the problem is that I get the "Login failed for user. Cannot open database requested by the login. The login failed" error. What do I need to do to make it work again?

Comment: Are you restoring the backups to a different server or instance? The server principal SIDs (logins) won't match the database users any more so you'll need to remap the users to logins again via `ALTER USER`.

Comment: One principle in programming is [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself): both your `else` blocks share almost the same code - move the same code into one (sub) procedure and call that.

Comment: @AmigoJack Thanks, will do that after I figure out the other problem.

Answer (score 0):

If there are SQL auth logins from the backup source that you've manually recreated on the destination server, you can do a couple of things:

1. re-create the login on the destination server `WITH SID=0x...` matching the SID on the source
2. after restoring the database, run `ALTER USER {foo} WITH LOGIN = {bar};` to re-map the user to the login on the destination server.

Some of these tasks can be made easier using code from Andy Mallon's blog post [here](https://am2.co/2021/07/dba-serverlogins/). And clearly you'll need to do this using the account you restored the database with, not the account you're trying to connect with.